Aiogram. Как сделать, чтобы после подачи заявки о вступлении в канал, пользователю писал сообщение бот?
Я не разбираюсь в теме, поэтому не могу понять, как реализовать такое?
Бота я создал, дал ему права администратора канала, он работает.
Мне нужен пример кода, чтобы после подачи заявки на вступление, бот писал этому пользователю.
Сейчас у меня получается так, что бот пишет сообщение в канал, как только приходит новая заявка на вступление, а мне нужно, чтобы он писал сообщение пользователю, отправившему заявку.
import asyncio
import logging
import sys
from app.config import token
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, html
from aiogram.client.default import DefaultBotProperties
from aiogram.enums import ParseMode
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart
from aiogram.types import Message, chat_join_request, User
TOKEN = token

dp = Dispatcher()

@dp.chat_join_request()
async def lalala(message: chat_join_request):
    await message.answer("Hello, my friend!")

async def main() -> None:
    bot = Bot(token=TOKEN, default=DefaultBotProperties(parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML))
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, stream=sys.stdout)
    asyncio.run(main())


Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Пробуйте искать так же на англ., вероятность найти ответ +100500%
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49968440/19983839
У вас есть примеры таких ботов, которые пишут пользователю в ответ на запрос вступить в группу? Прикрепите ссылку хотя бы на одного.
Насколько мне известно, в документации Telegram Bot Api написано: "Инициировать диалог с пользователем - бот не может". Первым должен написать пользователь нажав кнопку "Старт", а уже дальнейшее взаимодействие, может продолжаться и с сообщениями в направлении Бот -> Пользователь.
